# Creating Mixins using CSS Variables

Tags: css

This code is not working can someone please help me with this.

```
:root {
    --center: {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    };
}

.toolbar {
    @apply --toolbar-theme;
}
```

Comment: :root {
    --center: {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
}

.toolbar {
    @apply --toolbar-theme;
} try this

Comment: Where do you think `@apply` is coming from, or who do you think is handling it?

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to say can you please explain little bit more.

Comment: I am trying to implement code at this url https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-apply-rule/